# Default RESTAdapter with EAK

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

How do you set the default adapter as the ember-data RESTAdapter with ember-app-kit? The docs aren't very clear on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ember-app-kit/app/adapters/application.js` file, is the place where you define the application adapter.

Just change it content to:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter;
```

And it will use the RESTAdapter.

If you want to override some properties you can do the following:

```
var MyRESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});

export default MyRESTAdapter;
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems as if the `store` is not getting set on my models, though. For example, https://gist.github.com/311e3466fdc016eaa5f3 this returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createRecord' of undefined`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Strange using createRecord works for me. Do you receive some additional error in console.

Comment: I recommend you to accept my answer because your initial problem, adapter lookup, was resolved. Right? And then create another question with this problem.

Comment: Make sure that your call to `this.store` is within a function, not inline as the value of the model.